# Java Annotation Processing how to check if VariableElement is a primitive type(int, float) or an object some class

Tags: java, annotations, android-annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I have a class

```
public class SomeClass {

    @CustomAnnotation1
    String stringProperty = "LALALA";

    @CustomAnnotation1
    int integerProperty;

    @CustomAnnotation1
    ClassObject classObject;
}
```

CustomAnnotation1 is a custom annotation defined by me which can be put over any Field. Suppose class `ClassObject` is something like

```
public class ClassObject {

    @CustomAnnotation1
    public String someOtherString;

    public String log;
}
```

**What I want to achieve** - If my annotation is put on any field which is not a primitive type, I want to access all the fields of that class.

**My Approach** - Get all the fields annotated with `CustomAnnotation1`, iterate over all of them and if it is non-primitive, get all the fields inside that class and process.

**What I've tried** - I am able to get all the elements annotated with my annotation using the below code in my `AbstractProcessor` class.

```
Collection<? extends Element> annotatedElements = roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation1.class);
List<VariableElement> variableElements = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(annotatedElements);
```

**Questions** -

- I've researched a lot about the `VariableElement` class but unable to find a way to check if the field is primitive or not. Can this be done?
- Is there any better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VariableElement.asType().getKind().isPrimitive()`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500 There isno why, just the API really there.